# Symfony RequestStack::$requests is empty

Tags: symfony, request

I'm investigating a bug I have with the Symfony framework, version 2.8.

When I create a service and I inject the `request_stack` service to it, calling the `RequestStack::getCurrentRequest()` method will result in an null `$request`, even though I definitely have a Request because I'm in a Symfony Request/Response lifecycle.

The `RequestStack::$requests` is an array of the requests Symfony created during its lifecycle, and `getCurrentRequest()` simply returns the last one of them. What I don't understand, is why the `$requests` array is empty and no Request is added to it at the time I call the `getCurrentRequest()` method.

Can someone explain me why and how I can fix that bug? I presume there's an event listener and my service has the priority over it, but I can't find where and how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide suitable code which let us reproduce this issue.

Comment: There is definitely something going wrong here. Unless you're calling from a CLI you should have a request in the stack. Do you have the same problem of request being null when you add `Request $request` to the controller action parameters?

Comment: Probably because you are calling getCurrentRequest from the constructor.  The request processing has not started yet when your service is created.  Call getCurrentRequest when you actually need the request.  BTW, it is not a bug but rather operator error.

Comment: Hi, yes I do call the getCurrentRequest() from the constructor of my service, but it doesn't work even if I call this inside a setter.

If I inject the request service directly (which is a bad practice since RequestStack has to be used) Symfony tells me request belongs to another scope since I create this service in a Bundle/dependency and not in the master app, but if I force the injection, it works. Thanks for your help !